# Running App on Android Studio, Emulator opens up, but doesnt show app

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

hope you all doin fine.

I try to run my code in Android Studio(btw. if i do it on Visual Studio its the same), and the code is clean, he opens up the Virtual Device but doesnt show my app.

`Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode... Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... e: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Tigran\Desktop\jdk-12.0.2\bin\java" (in directory "C:\Users\Tigran\AppData\Local\kotlin\daemon"): CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden FAILURE: Build failed with an exception What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Tigran\Desktop\jdk-12.0.2\bin\java": CreateProcess error=2, Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights. Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 2m 26s Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`

This is the error im getting back. And i can remember that when i updated Android Studio there was a little check mark on deleting directories or smth like that, and i did hit that, so i think it stands in some connection to this problem.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: You might need to reinstall java jdk-12.0.2

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to this problem is as follows:

1-Open your flutter Project directory.

2-Change directory to android directory in your flutter project directory.

3-Pub get with file `pubspec.yaml`.

4-Clean Gradle and build gradle , if you need use this command `./gradlew clean build`.

5- Run Project.

If that doesn't work, you should reinstall the **Java JDK** and repeat the same steps .

Comment: how do i change project directory i looked it up in the internet but im not getting smarter at all. and how do i do step 4